# How can I keep the state from reseting even after I change the url with Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I´m trying to build a react NavBar that has a switch button that changes the theme of the page. The theme is a bootstrap theme that is passed in a  element to a helmet component, all within the navbar for now.

This switch button changes the state, and then a function, according to the state returns one of two  elements with different hrefs (bootstrap themes) that then it gets rendered in the helmet element.

The problem is, when I change between pages with Router, the state resets and so does the theme. Can you think of a solution? How do I keep the state even after changing pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can access state via props when pass in to you link.

```
<Link to={{
   pathname: '/yourpath',
   state: {
    yourObj
  }
}}>LinkName</Link>
```

To access props.location.state.yourObj